# SELECT interval where the number of interval is from table (redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In redshift, I have query

```
CREATE TABLE result_table AS(
  SELECT * FROM table_name
  WHERE issued_timestamp >= date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate())- interval '2 days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
        AND issued_timestamp < date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate())- interval '0 days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
);
```

Can I select where the number of interval is from another table?
For example I have a table `day_interval`

```
day_since|day_until
21|5
```

So I can query like this

```
CREATE TABLE result_table AS(
  SELECT * FROM table_name
  WHERE issued_timestamp >= date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate())- interval '2 days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
        AND issued_timestamp < date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate())- interval '5 days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
);
```

I tried

```
CREATE TABLE result_table AS(
  SELECT * FROM table_name
  WHERE issued_timestamp >= date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate())- interval (SELECT day_since FROM "day_interval")' days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
        AND issued_timestamp < date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate())- interval '0 days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
);
```

but didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interval is always a literal.
`interval 'x' days` or `interval x days` won't work, **but** -
`x * interval '1' days` will.

```
CREATE TABLE result_table AS(
  SELECT * FROM table_name
  WHERE issued_timestamp >= date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate()) - (SELECT day_since FROM "day_interval") * interval '1 days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
        AND issued_timestamp < date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate())- interval '0 days' + interval '17 hours')*1000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want a `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE result_table AS
  SELECT t.*
  FROM table_name t JOIN
       day_interval di
       ON t.issued_timestamp >= date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate()) - di.day_since * interval '2 days' + interval '17 hours') * 1000 AND
          t.issued_timestamp < date_part(epoch, trunc(getdate()) - di.day_until * interval '0 days' + interval '17 hours') * 1000
);
```